# Each UDP packet has many duplicates (like 10-15 repeat) How can I solve this?

Tags: c#, networking, duplicates, udp

In my code, I'm reading some information from a software with serial port and sending(writing) it to another software with udp. But some of my data duplicates 10-15 times. How can I solve this problem and where is the problem in my code ?

This is the read part:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            CONTROLFLAG = 1; //Veri gönderme kontrolü için flag
            isConnectCheck = 2;

            try
            {
                //Veriler 1 byte alınarak okunur.
                serialPortReceiver = (SerialPort)sender;

                readedByteLenght = serialPortReceiver.Read(receivedData, 0, 1);

                if (receivedData[0] == 170)  //Gelen byte SOF'e eşittir.
                {
                    List<byte> all = new List<byte>();  //Liste eklenir.
                    all.Add(receivedData[0]);
                    readedByteLenght++;
                    serialPortReceiver.Read(receivedData, 0, 1);
                    all.Add(receivedData[0]);

                    if (all[1] == 85)
                    {
                        readedByteLenght++;
                        serialPortReceiver.Read(receivedData, 0, 1);
                        all.Add(receivedData[0]);

                        do
                        {
                            if (serialPortReceiver.Read(receivedData, 0, 1) == 1)
                            {
                                all.Add(receivedData[0]);
                                readedByteLenght++;
                            }
                        } while (readedByteLenght < all[2] + 7);

                        if (Crc32Mpeg2Check(all, all[2] + 3)) //len = crc kısmı olmadan uzunluk verisi yani crc'si hesaplanacak veri
                        {
                            byte[] allData = new byte[118];
                            for (int i = 0; i < all.Count; i++)
                            {
                                allData[i] = all.ElementAt(i);
                            }

                            Thread listener = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                SendToMADGroundTerminal(allData);

                            });
                            listener.IsBackground = true;
                            listener.Start();  //Send data to MAD Ground Station via UDP (ethernet) - start UDP communication (Send) //SEND DATA TO MAD GROUND TERMINAL SOFTWARE

                            all.Clear(); //Liste temizlenir.

                            if(m_startFlag == 2)
                            {
                                serialPort.Close();
                            }

                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            }
       
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
            }
        }
```

This is the write part and udp connection to other software:

```
public void SendDataToMAD()
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_startFlag == 1)
                {
                    Thread listener = new Thread(() =>
                    {

                        TrigonomeryFunction();
                        EstimateRegionInCoordinaatSystem();
                        FlightSimulatorData();
                    });
                    listener.IsBackground = true;
                    listener.Start();
                }

                else
                {
                    ParameterSimulatorData();
                }

                SendCommand(DataPacket); //Serial port tx ile gömülüye veri gönderme fonksiyonu (Simülasyon yazılımından MAD gömülü yazılımına veri gönderir.)
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
            }

            //finally
            //{
            //    serialPort.Close();
            //}
        }

        public void SendCommand(byte[] command)
        {
            try
            {
                if (serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
                    serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                }

                else
                {
                    CloseComPortConnection();
                }

                //SendMADHeathDataToMADGroundTerminal(MadHealthState);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
            }
        }


public void SendToMADGroundTerminal(byte[] send_buffer)
        {
            AppBase.MainDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Flight();

                    m_ethernetPortNumber = Convert.ToInt32(EthernetPort_TextBox.Text);
                    m_ipAddress = FirstByteTextBox.Text + "." + SecondByteTextBox.Text + "." + ThirdByteTextBox.Text + "." + FourthByteTextBox.Text;

                    Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                    IPAddress send_to_address = IPAddress.Parse(SendingIPAddress);  //Gönderilecek Bilgisayarın IP Adresi
                    IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, EthernetPortNumber);  //Ortak Port numarası (Ethernet Haberleşmesi sağlamak için)

                    sending_socket.SendTo(send_buffer, sending_end_point);
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                    isConnectCheck = 2;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
                }
            });
        }
```

This is the image of data duplicate in mysql:
[Data duplicate(repeat) in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29a7Y.jpg)

Comment: If you just want some computers to talk to each other over the network there are much easier methods to use. I found MQTT to be fairly easy, but there are plenty of alternatives like gRPC, rabbitMQ, http, etc. Using low level protocols tend to be error prone unless you really know what you are doing, and the "best effort" model of UDP certainly does not help.

Comment: This is not my code, I need to use udp and I am trying to debug this problem. Do you see any part that triggers data duplicate ?